React Native, navigation setOptions problem
I have a problem with react navigation.
In my view i put my option navigation with setOptions: headerRight.
Eveything work when i change my view, but when i reduce the app in the second view, and i come back the icon from the first view appear, and after a few second, the icon from the second view come back... I dont understand why
Thanks a lot !!
my code:
I have a first navigation :
     <DashboardBottomtBarNavigator.Screen
        name="Planning"
        component={EventsTopBar}
        options={{
          unmountOnBlur: true,
          lazy: false,
          title: t('BOTTOM_BAR_ITEM_PLANNING') as string,
          tabBarIcon: ({ color, size }) => (
            <AntDesignIcon color={color} size={size} name="calendar" />
          ),
        }}
      />

and in EventsTopBar i have 2 other navigation:
      <EventsTopBarNavigator.Navigator
        initialRouteName="EventsToday"
        screenOptions={{
          lazy: true,
          tabBarStyle: {
            backgroundColor: colors.headerBackground,
          },
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: Palette.lighterGrey,
          tabBarActiveTintColor: Palette.white,
          tabBarIndicatorStyle: { backgroundColor: Palette.lighterGrey },
          swipeEnabled: true,
        }}
      >
        <EventsTopBarNavigator.Screen
          options={{ title: t('EVENTS_TODAY') as string }}
          component={EventViewNavigator}
          name="EventsToday"
          initialParams={{ eventsType: EventOption.Today, setBadge: setBadge, onOpenActionSheet: onOpenActionSheetEventFilters }}
        />
        <EventsTopBarNavigator.Screen
          options={{ title: t('EVENTS_ALL') as string }}
          component={EventViewNavigator}
          name="EventsAll"
          initialParams={{ eventsType: EventOption.All, setBadge: setBadge, onOpenActionSheet: onOpenActionSheetEventsFilters }}
        />

      </EventsTopBarNavigator.Navigator>

and next,
type export const EventViewNavigator = ({ route }: NavProps) => {
  const type = route.name
  const { onOpenActionSheet } = route.params;

  if (type === 'EventsAll') {
    return (
      <EventInfiniteView
        eventsType={route.params.eventsType}
        setBadge={route.params.setBadge}
        onOpenActionSheet={onOpenActionSheet}
      />
    )
  }

  if (type === 'EventsToday') {
    return (
      <EventView
        eventsType={route.params.eventsType}
        setBadge={route.params.setBadge}
        onOpenActionSheet={onOpenActionSheet}
      />
    )
  }
}


and in EventInfiniteView and EventView i put my options, different for the 2 view:
    navigation.getParent()?.setOptions({
        headerRight: () => (
            <EventHeaderRight
                type={"EventsAll"}
                onPress={onOpenActionSheet}
                onPressCalendar={onPressCalendar}
            />
        )
    })



